# IntelliJ complaining "for statement does not loop"?

Tags: java, for-loop, intellij-idea

This is the code I have:

```
public enum Modification {
    NONE, SET, REMOVE;
}

boolean foo(List<S> sList){
    for (S s : sList) {
        Modification modification = s.getModification();
        switch (modification) {
            case SET:
            case REMOVE:
                return true;
            /*
            case NONE:
                break;
            */
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And when the code is as seen above, IntelliJ will say:

> 'for' statement does not loop less... ()  Reports any instance of for,
> while and do statements whose bodies are guaranteed to execute at most
> once. Normally, this is an indication of a bug.

Only if I make the following change, IntelliJ will be happy:

```
for (S s : sList) {
    Modification modification = s.getModification();
    switch (modification) {
        case SET:
        case REMOVE:
            return true;
        case NONE:
            break;
    }
}
```

Why is my for loop not looping if **case NONE:**  is not included in the switch statement?

Comment: there are more IDE's that 'require' a default option. My guess: IntelliJ considers all the options you implemented as case as the only possible ones, and they all perform a return on the first iteration.

Comment: i assume these are your only three cases right?, so basically its saying you are going to hit one of the first two and instantly return true, therefore not looping, just add a `default case`

Comment: @AlexHall with `case NONE` it will iterate more than once, check again.

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or are you really intending to use this? It's generally considered bad practice to use the fall through of a switch statement so I would re-write this altogether.

Comment: @BenThurley it's common practice to group two or more cases together like that. This is one of the uses of fallthrough that is generally considered ok.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I disagree. Using the fall through is a bit of a trick, this isn't a good thing. It's hard to read and can cause problems down the line when new cases need to be added. More trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Also I'm not a fan of using multiple return statements in blocks of code like this. It's a glorified goto statement which can also cause problems with maintenance. What's wrong with something like `return sList.contains(Modification.REMOVE);`?

Comment: @BenThurley return sList.contains(Modification.REMOVE); is not what is being returned here.

Comment: Koray's example source may be a simplified snippet to show the problem with IntelliJ, and it may not be possible to use `contains` in his actual code. In your example, he would have to do `return sList.contains(Modification.REMOVE) || sList.contains(Modification.SET)` which would loop through the list twice, instead of looping once as it does in his code.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yes, it is indeed simplified for sake of asking question

Comment: The point is that IntelliJ has got it wrong.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I am not sure about if IntelliJ is getting it wrong, since it seems Idebrujin agrees with IntelliJ that the first version will NOT really loop..

Comment: No it really does loop.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Am I misunderstanding Idebrujin 's answer?

Comment: Not sure, as I don't understand his answer either. But add some print statements at the start of your for loop and you'll see that it does loop.

Comment: @KorayTugay @Kiltos it shall only loop when the `return` statement is not being executed and the only way `return` won't execute without `case NONE` is when the first two cases don't match with switch, which can happen.

Comment: @rustedbraid so, it does indeed loop? I think Idebrujin 's answer is bit confusing to be honest..

Comment: Yes it shall loop. Why don't you give it a try? Try writing console statements and check whether the statement prints multiple times.

Comment: Yes, it does loop, Intellij is wrong.

Comment: I see there is an uncaught case. Thus it should either have a default case or catch the NONE case. My IDE (IntelliJ) doesn't tell me it is not looping by the way.

Comment: I tested it with Android Studio 2.0 (IntelliJ 15)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just tried this in eclipse and you end up with a compiler warning on the switch statement.

> The enum constant NONE needs a corresponding case label in this enum switch on Modification

To resolve the warning I'm given the following options.

- Add default case
- Add missing case statements
- Add @SuppressWarnings 'incomplete-switch' to foo()

If I add the missing case statement then the warning no longer appears. The same as adding the missing case makes your <strike>error</strike> warning disappear from intellij.

Without the statement for case NONE you can only see two cases, both of which return true. Without knowing the structure of Modification and the extra value of NONE it looks like this loop would just return true on the first iteration of the loop.

Of course the compiler should actually know that there are more values for Modification than SET and REMOVE so the warning is just for good style. Basically your code works but here's how to improve it.

I would choose to add a default statement rather than the missing case. This would be more future proof in case more values are later added to the enum. E.G.

```
switch (modification) 
{
  case SET:
  case REMOVE:
    return true;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Personally I'm not a fan of using the fall through on switch statements. What you gain in making the code concise you lose in legibility IMHO. If someone later comes and adds a case between SET and REMOVE it could introduce a bug. Also, having a return statement mid-way through a method can also cause problems. If someone wants to add some code just before the return they may miss all the places. If the method is very simple then multiple returns is fine but you've stated that this is a simplified example and so if this block of code is complicated I would avoid it.

If you're able to use Java 8 then this looks to be the perfect use case for the new stream API. Something like the following should work.

```
return sList.stream().anyMatch(
  modification -> (modification==Modification.SET || modification==Modification.REMOVE)
);
```

Comment: The best answer to go with:)

Comment: By the way, it's not an error message, but a warning; or, to be precise, it's what IntelliJ calls an "inspection", which appears when you put your cursor over the `for` keyword. So the message is misleading, as it should give a warning about incomplete switch instead, but in any case the functional style using streams is much better.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the clarification, the question doesn't say either way if it's a warning or error so I must have just assumed it was an error.

Answer (score 2):

i assume these are your only three cases right?, so basically its saying you are going to hit one of the first two and instantly return true, therefore not looping, just add a `default` case and everything should work ok, this is good practice also btw.

basically it cant see a case where it doesnt just return instantly without iterating the loop

Answer (score 1):

I'd say its a false positive.

1st indication:
If you run your code through a debugger - and have elements with NONE modification in the list before an element with other modifications - it will actually loop.

2nd indication:
When you look at the generated bytecode, it transforms the switch statement to (sort of - its not *exactly* the same)

```
for (S s : sList) {
    Modification modification = s.getModification();
        switch (modification.ordinal()) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                return true;
    }
}
```

If you put that in your code, IntelliJ does not complain.

3rd indication:
the warning dissappears if you put an additional statement *before* the return, i.e. `System.out.println();`

```
 switch (modification) {
     case SET:
     case REMOVE:
       System.out.println()
       return true;
```

Seems you tricked the inspection with the missing case label and could simply ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I think that IntelliJ's inspections is wrong. I reported it to [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154177)

Edit : it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your switch case always breaks or returns. In the first case, you do nothing aka it `falls through`. The second case `return`s which causes both the switch and the loop to stop. In the third case you `break` the switch statement which causes it to stop. It does not however stop the for loop (aka, it keeps iterating).

Either add specific functionality for the `SET` case or change your behaviour on the `REMOVE` and `NONE` cases.

```
public enum Modification {
    NONE, SET, REMOVE;
}

boolean foo(){
    for (S s : sList) {
        final Modification modification = s.getModification();
        switch (modification) {
            case SET:
               // This case falls through to the REMOVE case
            case REMOVE:
                return true; // This statement stops the switch, loop and returns true
            case NONE:
                break; // This statement stops the switch and continues the loop.
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your switch is not looping without the `NONE` case because `return` breaks the loop and returns a value from the function. `break` breaks the switch loop but continues the for loop.

---

By request of OP an extra explanation.

Falling through means the next case will be executed until a stop (`break` or `return`) is reached. This makes the following code snippets equivelant:

```
case SET:
case REMOVE:
    return true;
```

is the same as:

```
case SET:
    return true;
case REMOVE:
    return true;
```

Comment: @rustedbrain How is this correct? The OP's code does indeed loop many times even though IntelliJ says it doesn't.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou If you read the entire question and my answer you'd see that's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have misunderstood you. You said "Your switch is not looping without the NONE case" but in fact it is indeed looping without the NONE case.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand.. 'Your switch case always breaks or returns. In the first case, you do nothing aka it falls through.' Ok, so the loop should continue, no? If I do not return true, next switch should be evaluated?

Comment: By doing nothing in the `SET` case, the code `falls through`, this means the code in the next case (and the next and the next..) will be executed until a stop (`break` or `return`) is reached. In your case, the code in case `SET` will be executed, which is empty, and next the code in `REMOVE` will be executed. Effectively, the `SET` case also returns true. Check my updated answer for an extra explanation/comparison.

Comment: How can you claim "In your case, the code in case SET will be executed, which is empty, and next the code in REMOVE will be executed. " ? modification may be NONE, so code in case SET will not be executed..

Comment: There's 2 different things here. Because of the fall through, both `SET` and `REMOVE` result in `return true;` causing both the switch and the for loop to stop. When `NONE` is added, the switch case will break, but the for loop will continue.

Comment: @Idebrujin So say we do not have case NONE added.. And we have 10 instances of "s" in or sList and all of them have modification NONE. What you are claiming is, the switch statement will be executed only once, right? Not 10 times? But just once?

Comment: @KorayTugay, No, it will be executed 10 times. The for loop will still iterate over all its elements. The `break` merely stops the switch statement, not the for loop.

Comment: @ldebruijn thats what! It will execute 10 times. So IDE is wrong.

Comment: @rustedbrain I don't believe so. OP said IntelliJ throws that error when the `NONE` case is not included. In other words, the switch will always result in `return true;` which does actually stop the for loop. It will therefor only iterate once. When the OP adds the `NONE` case, the possible flow of the `break` statement causes only the switch statement to terminate, not the for loop. Therefor it will loop. It's still perfectly possible it will only iterate once if the first element is not a `NONE` case. But it's still loopable.

Comment: @Idebruijn: "the switch will always result in return true;" - not if the first element in the list contains NONE. (Even if case NONE is not included in the switch.)

Comment: `NONE` case is not included in the `switch` but it can be passed as a parameter.

Comment: Yes. So when it is passed as a parameter, and both the `cases` don't match the `switch` then it will loop. But IDE is giving warning that it won't.

Comment: @rustedbrain I really don't get what you are trying to say. Are you saying that a case without a break doesn't jump to the next case?

Comment: just see my answer